# Rendering vertex colours from imported WRL object

Tags: rendering, vertices, vertex-paint

Every time I have installed Blender over the many years I get so frustrated... Inexperienced, and now using ver 2.91.0

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Import from ZBrush a polypainted (vertex painted) object and render it using either Eevee or Cycles.

Here's what I CAN do:
Import a WRL file with all colour info. I know the info is there because when I switch to Vertex Paint Mode I see the painted object just fine.

What I cannot do:
Enable options to allow me to see vertex paint while in Edit Mode.
Cannot render the colours at all.

From what I've been reading I need to assign a material. I believe I have done that. I cannot find the top row of icons that I am used to from past versions as seen in this image:
[image]

I used to be able to add materials very easily. Now, I'm not sure I have done it correctly or checked off the right boxes to allow me to see the vertex paint. I can see the object change colour when I do so, but not the vertex paint.

As for rendering. Useless. Not even a hint of my painted areas, simply the object coloured to that set in the material panel.

Any hints for pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t panic. This will be easy.

First off, that “row of icons” is the tabs of the Properties Editor, and is now on the side of that same editor. Things work generally the same way, except Blender Internal Render has been scrapped, so things in the Textures tab generally do not affect things in the Materials tab: You use shader texture nodes instead. The textures made in the Texture tab of the Properties Editor are for other purposes like compositing.

Secondly, you can input color into your material with the Vertex Color Node. If you do not know how to use material shader nodes, it’s time to learn. They are very intuitive, and both Cycles render and the new EEVEE render use them.

Refer to the blender manual at docs.blender.org under:

1. Editors -> Properties
2. Rendering -> Shader Nodes
   ...for more information.

Comment: Excellent. With this as a start I was able to "git 'er done"!  The vertex paint still doesn't show up when in Edit mode, but that doesn't concern me. It does now render fine. Thanks.